# Airflow None Schedule is not working. Tasks are still running automatically

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have an airflow dag which i don't want to schedule. I'm using `schedule_interval:None` in my dag file but the dag is still running automatically once it is deployed.
Airflow version used: `2.1.0`

Airflow Screenshot Attached.
[image]
I'm using the following python code in my dag file.

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import croniter
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator



default_args = {
'owner': 'test-owner',
'depends_on_past': True,
'start_date': '2021-11-14',
'email': ['test.owner@gmail.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
'schedule_interval':None,
 }

 dag = DAG(
'test-dag',
default_args=default_args,
description='test description'
)

def test_task(ds, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    print(ds)


task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="test_task",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=test_task,
    op_kwargs={"image": "value"},
    dag=dag,
)
```

Also I have setup airflow env variables to the following:

- `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "False"`
- `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL: 30`
- `AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "False"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `schedule_interval` in the `default_args`, which propagates the given dict as arguments to all operators in the DAG. However, `schedule_interval` is an argument on `DAG`, so you must set it there:

```py
 dag = DAG(
'test-dag',
default_args=default_args,
description='test description',
schedule_interval=None,
)
```